# SpriteKit physics world scale in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsworld

I am working on this game where I have a `SKNode` (named `objectsNode`) which contains all of the game sprites.

Running on **iOS 7.0x** Collision detection works great between the sprites until I try to zoom out the `objectsNode` (by modifying its `xScale` and `yScale` properties).

It seems that the physics body's size of each sprite remains the same as if it was not affected by the scale. I ran across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22344156/986169) which might confirm it is a bug with iOS 7.0 but I could not find a more convincing source.

Running on iOS 7.1 works great and collision is correctly detected when zooming out the objects node.

Is there a way to fix this or should I just deploy the game to iOS 7.1 devices and above (is it recommended to so ?) ?

Comment: If it works correctly in iOS 7.1 but not in iOS 7.0 you have all the reason to require 7.1. It's not limiting your targetable devices (7.0 devices can run 7.1) and that users wouldn't get your app because they refuse to upgrade from 7.0 to 7.1 is marginal at best.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for clearing this out. Can you clarify on "7.0 devices can run 7.1)" ? how is it possible ?

Comment: Apple only stops supporting certain devices with new major versions (ios 7 dropped the 3gs, ios 8 dropped iphone 4 support). A device that runs version x.0 can in all likelihood upgrade to x.1 x.2 x.3 and so on - it's only up to the user whether device gets updated or not. I think 0.1 version steps are very quickly installed on all devices that had the previous version (faster than major versions that is). It'll be hard to find an iOs 7.0 device these days.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D oh of course you meant by upgrading. (I thought you meant somehow running 7.1 apps on iOS 7.0 ). Thanks alot for the info. You are welcome to post these as answers for me to accept.